# В XML файле не прописывается путь к классу

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

При прописке в `XML` пути для `бина` выдает ошибку `cannot resolve class or package`.  Да и при создании конструктора тоже ругается. Про версии молчу, там все самое актуальное стоит. Сборка на `Мавен`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял в чем проблема. Если xml-файл и сам класс находятся в одной директории, то путь указывать не надо. Можно просто написать:

```java
<bean id="app" class="App">
```